# Is passing global variables to functions problematic?

Tags: c

Consider following function declaration:

```
int abmeld(char *strsend)
```

which is called like this

```
abmeld(str);
```

where **str** is a global variable declared and initialised at the start of the program file (after the includes) like this:

```
char str[300] = "";
```

Now I already know this is unnecessary code (you can access and modify the char array from within any function without passing it anyways), but is this actually otherwise problematic?

Are there consequences (like hard error possibilities, or undefined behavior) that can happen as the result of passing an already globally scoped variable to a function?

Comment: The function does not care where the parameter comes from.

Comment: A pointer is a pointer. It doesn't matter what is the scope of the pointed variable. BTW I'd suggest to make the global static: `static char str[300] = {0};`

Comment: What do you mean with "problematic"? If you mean unnecessary or possibly bad design then the answer is yes. If you mean that it won't work, then no, it will indeed work.

Comment: @DarioP Things that could go wrong, like UB and the like, in this case.

Comment: @Magisch: your mention of UB should go into the question, not in comments

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I put it in the question, thanks.

Comment: Side issue: calling `abmeld(char *strsend)` with `char str[300]` is in itself a potential issue as `abmeld()`, which can change `str[]`, does not know the size of the array.  I would expect `abmeld(const char *strsend)` or `abmeld(char *strsend, size_t size)`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I would say the opposite, it is almost never problematic to pass a global to a function (and it is usually dirty to use a lot of globals, the code becoming unreadable).

A function which depends lightly (or not at all) on the global state is often *more readable* and more understandable than a function using a lot of global (or even static) variables. A global variable changed in many functions makes your program messy to understand.

<sup>(never forget that you code not only for the computer, but also for your colleagues -perhaps even yourself in a few months- who would have to improve your source code)</sup>

Also, functions using global state are typically not [reentrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29).

At last, [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is mostly orthogonal to global vs argument data. In particular, a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) can occur both with a global variable, or with a pointer to some array  (such as an argument or some local variable) .

<sup>A very crude rule of thumb would be to avoid loading the developer's brain with more than 7 items ([magical number 7, + or - 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magical_Number_Seven,_Plus_or_Minus_Two)); hence the folklore rule to avoid more than 7 arguments or more than 7 globals.</sup>

Comment: Global constants are much less harmful in this respect - they don't affect reentrancy, for instance.

Answer (score 12):

There *is* a case where this could be problematic: if `abmeld` already does something with the `str` global.  As a trivial example:

```
extern char str[300];

void abmeld(const char *s)
{
    snprintf(str, 300, "abmeld: %s\n", s);
}
```

then `abmeld(str)` has undefined behavior, because `snprintf` has undefined behavior when its destination buffer overlaps any of its inputs.

This demonstrates one of the reasons global variables are troublesome: in order to know what's safe to pass as an argument to `abmeld`, you have to know not only that it writes to `str` (which would surely be documented), but *how it does that* — it could have been written

```
void abmeld(const char *s)
{
    size_t n = strlen(s);
    size_t maxcopy = min(n, 300 - sizeof "abmeld: \n");
    size_t after = maxcopy + sizeof "abmeld: " - 1;

    memmove(str + sizeof "abmeld: " - 1, s, maxcopy);
    memcpy(str, "abmeld: ", sizeof "abmeld: " - 1);
    str[after] = '\n';
    str[after+1] = 0;
}
```

and then it would have well-defined behavior no matter what `s` points to, as long as it's a valid C-string.

Answer (score 8):

> Now I already know this is unnecessary code (you can access and modify
>   the char array from within any function without passing it anyways),
>   but is this actually otherwise problematic?

It doesn't matter to the function whether it receives locally or globally defined variable. Issues with global variables are related sometimes to the fact that you might not know from which parts of the program you are accessing/changing its value. Thread safety maybe also relevant.

Comment: The program in question has no threading and only one program file, but thanks for pointing that out anyways.

Answer (score 7):

It's very, VERY common to pass globals to functions. Example:

```
const char* global = "Example";

void foo() {
  printf("%s\n",  global );
}
```

Obviously this passes a global to `printf`. The C language *by design* makes this usage safe. A buggy implementation that trips over this would quickly be called out.

Comment: This question is not in any way about c++ though.

Comment: @Magisch: Overlooked that bit, but the principle still applies to C as well. Edited.

Comment: The difference to the question is: 1. the global is const 2. the global is not passed as argument to the function.

Comment: @StefanW: In case you missed it, it's being passed to `printf`. I had to add `foo` because you can't have that `printf` statement outside a function. That said, this code also would work with `char global[] = `

Answer (score 6):

No, not at all.

> Now I already know this is unnecessary code

Not always. In the case when your function does not have a default argument, then you have to comply with the function prototype and pass the global variable. The function won't care, whether the pointer points to local or global variable, though.

```
/* main.c */
char str[300] = {0};
int abmeld(char *strsend)
{
  /* Do something...process strsend */
  return 0;
}

int main( void )
{
  abmeld(str); /*Cannot pass void here as abmeld expects a char* */

  char localstr[10] = {0};
  abmeld(localstr);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you complete the code to demonstrate when we have to "comply with the function syntax" better?

Answer (score 3):

You want to pass global variable to the function. It's simple that function you are using, requires parameter then you have to pass the parameters of the type of the argument that is required in the function.

Here, there is no concern or issue for passing a global variable or a local variable. You have to take care of the datatype of the argument that is to be passed.

Answer (score 3):

1. The method `abmeld(char *)` is only supposed to modify/work with the argument provided to it. While it may be bad to pass a global variable to this method, yet that doesn't prohibit anyone from calling this method with any other char *.

   - For example, if this method checks whether the string pointed to is palindrome, then writing this method exemplifies good coding. Now anyone can call it every time he/she wants to know whether the string is palindrome or not.
2. > Now I already know this is unnecessary code (you can access and modify the char array from within any function without passing it anyways), but is this actually otherwise problematic?

   - It may not be unnecessary code as explained above. The purpose of writing a new method is to compartmentalize one piece of work. In other words, *a method should do only **one thing.*** Unless the method `abmeld(char *)` has been written to exclusively modify that particular global variable (and even that may be a good thing), the code is perfectly ok the way it has been written as long as it is doing *one thing* with the argument provided to it.
   - There are numerous examples where this code may be problematic and the problems are intuitive. For example, there may be more methods which may be modifying/working on the global string. But, those problems are the problems which arise whenever you use a global variable. To get rid of those issues, you have to get rid of the global var and not the method because it isn't the method's fault that it is being used with a global var.
3. > Are there consequences (like hard error possibilities, or undefined behavior) that can happen as the result of passing an already globally scoped variable to a function?

   - Cannot say this authoritatively but I don't know of any. Didn't read any book either which advised against passing global vars to functions.