# Variable name precedence in c

Tags: c

This is [a follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35309562/is-passing-a-global-variable-to-functions-anyways-problematic)

Consider following example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int asdf = 5;
int main(void) {
    sub(10);
    return 0;
}
int sub (int asdf)
{
    printf("%d\n",asdf);
}
```

In this case both the global variable and the local argument use the same name, `asdf`. The code outputs `10`, so the local variable is used. No compilation error or warning is thrown.

The global variable is still accessible from within `sub()`, as evidenced by when I change `sub`'s declaration to

```
int sub (int asd)
```

the code outputs 5. So I know `sub()` can access the global variable, yet it does not.

I was unable to find a clear definition about scope precedence in the c standard, so my question is:

Considering the scenario above, is naming local and global variables the same merely bad practice or does it invoke errors/UB?

Comment: Using global variables is bad practice, unless they are constants.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm

Comment: It is not UB, but sure as can be, you'll get an error in your code, sooner or later.

Comment: Also it's worth noting that some big projects with a big amount of legacy code and global variables, name those global variables w/ special prefixes which differ those variables from the rest

Comment: @MsYvette When I change the declaration of `sub` to `int sub (int asd)` basicly changing the local variable name.

Comment: *is naming local and global variables the same merely bad practice*  -  Sometimes, it is considered a bad practice because it could lead to errors. In OO languages, its actually considered a good practice to pass parameters with the same names as instance fields in a class (in a constructor). So that you could do `this.x = x` assignments. Other that that, if you are calling methods other than setters / constructors with params same as global field names, it is indeed a bad practice

Comment: The only problem here is missing function's prototype.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the C11 draft specification

> 6.2.1 **Scopes of identifiers**
>
> 4  [...]  If the declarator or type specifier that declares the
>   identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter
>   declarations in a function definition, the identifier has block scope,
>   which terminates at the end of the associated block.
>
> [...] If an identifier designates two different entities in the same
>   name space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity
>   (the inner scope) will end strictly before the scope of the other
>   entity (the outer scope). Within the inner scope, the identifier
>   designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared
>   in the outer scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.

So declaring a function parameter called `asdf` hides the global variable `asdf` within the function. Giving local and global variables the same identifier is bad practice, but allowed by the specification.

Answer (score 2):

> Considering the scenario above, is naming local and global variables the same merely bad practice or does it invoke errors/UB?

It is a bad practice and is not undefined behavior.

Consider a large program with many authors. In this case, it becomes difficult to track whether the variable being used is the one in the function or the global variable. Consider what happens if there is any change, if the original author has left the job and a new person is trying to understand the code. The program becomes more difficult to maintain.

This is also one of the reasons that you should avoid global variables in your code.

Answer (score 1):

It is called masking. When you have 2 same variables global is visible, but in function with parameter that have same name as global variable, function parameter have higher priority and masking global var. There will not be any invoked errors, but it is not good practice.

Comment: @undur_gongor Hiding.

Answer (score 1):

> [Formal parameters](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm), are treated as local variables with-in a function and they take precedence over global variables.

When you are using the method as follows, you are using the value of the variable being passed into the method as a parameter and this is determined on the method call:

```
int sub (int asdf)
{
    printf("%d\n",asdf);
}
```

eg:

```
sub(10); // asdf is being assigned the value of 10 and asdf is a different variable.
```

And is in effect the same as:

```
int sub (int adf)
{
    printf("%d\n",adf);
}
```

This fails to use the int parameter being passed into the method, so the global variable value is being used.

```
int sub (int adf)
{
    printf("%d\n",asdf);
}
```

Or you could call the original method like:

```
sub(asdf);
```

Either way, it has no real value naming it will a global variable. As it can be acheived using `int anything` and then the global variable can be accessed regardless. It does serve to be potentially confusing.

Any ambiguity of naming is considered bad practice.

Then there's the issues of using global variables, in a trivial way and this issues that this can cause with a program down the track, that has been mentioned in other answers here.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, Obviously it is a bad practice of naming two variables with same name.

You can differentiate with the help of keyword `extern` in these scenarios. Consider the below example.

```
#include <stdio.h>      

int a = 12;             

int main(void)          
{           
    int a = 15;             
    printf("Inside a's main local a = : %d\n", a);

    {
        extern int a;
        printf("In a global a = %d\n", a);
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

It will give op

```
Inside a's main local a = : 15
In a global a = 12
```

The compiler will not throw any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could call it bad practice, since it makes your code hard to read, but this will not cause an error. Local names always overwrite global names.

Imagine what would happen if local names did not overwrite global names: When you are interfacing with external code you often do not know the variable names that were already chosen. In this case the external code could suddenly change the value of your variables without you noticing it, just because you named a global variable the same as their local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Global variable is of course bad practice. Apart from that I don't see anything unexpected here about variable name precedence.

It's clear that **the compiler always looks for the variable name, say `x`, in the narrowest scope first**.

- If it does find `x` in local scope it will stop there, and never check for any other scope. This is your case when you have two variables `asdf`, one local, and one global. Because the compiler found `asdf` in `sub()`, it will never look for the global one. This behaviour is also called **name hiding**.
- Only when it doesn't find `x` in local scope, it will extend the search to broader scope, to the global scope.

This name hiding thing applies to different scopes as well, for example:

```
int i = 10;
for( int i = 5; i < 9; i++ )
{
    printf( "i = %d (inside for loop)\n", i );   // <-- i = 10 is hidden in this loop
}
printf( "i = %d (outside for loop)\n", i );
```

Btw, your prototype is incorrect, the return type should be `void`, not <s>`int`</s>.

```
void sub (int asdf);
```